# Upgrade to Skobbler SDK 2.4 - RouteCalculation Error

Tags: android, skmaps

we've just upgraded to Skobbler SDK 2.4 with our B2B-App. Now we've got following problem:

When calculation the Route, the App crashes with a nullpointer exception after calling **SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute**.

Here is the Code: (before upgrading it worked very well...)

```
SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
route.setStartCoordinate(ApplicationData.getInstance().getCurrentCoordinate());
route.setDestinationCoordinate(goal);
route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.PEDESTRIAN);
route.setAlternativeRouteModes(new ArrayList<SKRouteAlternativeSettings>());                            route.setRouteConnectionMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteConnectionMode.OFFLINE);
route.setRouteExposed(true);
route.setViaPoints(new ArrayList<SKViaPoint>());
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(this);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setAudioAdvisorSettings(new SKAdvisorSettings());
SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
```

The empty ArrayLists are tests for troubleshooting.

Is there a known issue with 2.4 or does anything else change with the Update?

Comment: Can you use the same code in the demo project and see if it still crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue as you. Routes worked with the old SDK, not so much with the new SDK.

After working through this a bit, I think your issue stems from this line:

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setAudioAdvisorSettings(new SKAdvisorSettings());
```

Try this code instead, for setting the audio advisor:

```
final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = new SKAdvisorSettings();
advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_EN);
advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(context.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor");
advisorSettings.setResourcePath(context.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages");
advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
advisorSettings.setAdvisorType(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorType.AUDIO_FILES);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setAudioAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
```

This code needs to be called some time before you calculate the route. I like to put mine well above the rest of the code, to keep them separate (i.e. the block that I just posted can go right above the code you posted)

The only change you might want to make is to change these lines:

```
advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(context.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor");
advisorSettings.setResourcePath(context.getFilesDir() + "/SKMaps/Advisor/Languages");
```

So that they point to the correct location of your SKMaps/Advisor folders. I am always using internal application storage, so context.getFilesDir() will always work for me. This won't work for you if you are using external storage, or storing the SKMaps file somewhere else.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Sadly, this does not work for us. We've only set the AdvisorSetting for debug purpose. We do not use it, but we tried to give the SDK an AdvisorSetting to prevent it running into a NullPointer. But still we got this problem. It seems we have to downgrade to 2.3 to get the navigation back running.

Comment: Have you tried exactly what I said though? It should work. You can't pass an empty advisor setting (e.g. "new SKAdvisorSettings()"). It will not automatically make any sound at all. Even if you aren't using the voice systems, you need to pass in a non-empty, non-null SKAdvisorSettings (i.e. the one I provided).

Comment: Thank you for this Comment! I've tried before with exactly using your code, but it did not work.
Now, after several tries putting the piece of code at different locations, it now works with using a "clean" AdvisorConfig. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In 2.4 now the advice config files are used for both audio files & text-to-speech - so I guess you have to set the audio advices before asking for a route (I'm verifying this internally)